# How do I "roll over" weapons and unlock the rocket launcher?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

I am having trouble figuring out how to "roll over" my guns and stuff from my first play file and unlocking the infinite rocket launcher. I have completed the main adventure.

How do I get these features?

I am trying the game on professional and would like to have these features while playing it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not uncommon for games to only allow a "[new game plus](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NewGamePlus)" on the difficulties which you have bested.

Your question hints you've only completed the game on normal. If so, you will not be able to carry all your weapons to professional, but will instead need to beat professional from scratch before being able to do that. If you were to try a new game in normal difficulty, you would be able to carry everything over. This is affirmed by the following [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/938877-resident-evil-4-wii-edition/faqs/49802), specifically:

> (Q) Why can't I start Professional
>   mode with all my weapon upgrades?
>
> (A) You have to start a new game when
>   first starting Professional mode, so
>   all  the upgrades that were obtained
>   on a previous normal save will not
>   carry over.  Be sure to save your
>   Professional mode bonus game once
>   Professional mode is  completed.

The same FAQ states the way to unlock the infinite rocket launcher:

> -- Infinite Rocket Launcher
>
> Complete the main game and the
>   merchant will sell it for 1000000
>   pesetas in the  bonus game of Leon's
>   main game on any difficulty.

Though it is not 100% clear whether that means that this unlockable will be available for purchase on all difficulties, or only on difficulties which you have finished once. Another quote hints that it is the latter:

> (Q) Can I use my unlocked weapons on
>   any mode?  For instance, can I unlock
>   the  P.R.L. 412 on Professional and
>   use it on normal mode?
>
> (A) Yes.  Just make sure to keep a
>   bonus game saved for each difficulty.

This is fairly easy to find out, however. Just get to the merchant on Professional and see if he has this.